# How do I get Czerka Crate-O-Matic

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

There is an Achievement `Those Things Exist?`

I have to get a `Czerka Crate-O-Matic` to get the achievement.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an incredibly rare drop (on the order of one in a billion) from any level 50 or higher enemy or lockbox.  There's not much you can do other than play the game and hope.

Of course, it can be traded and sold on the GTN.  On The Shadowlands it tends to sell for around 25 million.  Note that after buying and using it you could re-sell it, since it never binds.

Comment: Atleast it never binds:)